# Nginx Configuration for multiple codeignitor site under same tld

Tags: 16.04, php, nginx, php-fpm

I have a site `nginx.asdf.com:8082` which contains a CMS built using PHP (CodeIgnitor framework). I also have a similar site running under `nginx.asdf.com:8082/ghjkl/`. My Nginx configuration works for `nginx.asdf.com:8082` but not for `nginx.asdf.com:8082/ghjkl/`.
My current Nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 8082 default_server;
    listen [::]:8082 default_server;
    server_name nginx.asdf.com;

    root /var/www/nginx.asdf.com/ghjkl/;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/pages/views(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # removes access to "system" folder, also allows a "System.php" controller
    if ($request_uri ~* ^/system)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;


    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht
    {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

What should I do?

Comment: The issue I am mentioning is about Nginx configuration and not on permission issue.

Comment: the main problem i believe is in rewrite rules.

Comment: it's not the rewrite rules, it's how you proxy-pass to the backend.  The requested URI is different, and this can cause problems.  Is there a reason you need each site to be on the same port, and can't use multiple ports for multiple site roots/backends?

Comment: actually it is desired to run on port 80.  port 8082 is just for reference